# Sizeof enumerations

Tags: c, enums, size, enumeration, sizeof

Can someone explain why member `X` has different size than the enumerated type itself, despite being explicitly defined as `LL`? It seems counterintuitive that I need to cast `(enum e_x)X` member of the very same enumerated type to be sure it has the same size as the type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

enum e_x { X = 0LL, M = LLONG_MAX };

int main() {
 printf("%zu %zu %zu %zu\n",
         sizeof X,
         sizeof((enum e_x)X),
         sizeof(enum e_x),
         sizeof(long long));
}
```

Output:

```
 4 8 8 8
```

Expected:

```
 8 8 8 8
```

How can you deal with it when passing enumeration to a function that uses `va_arg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are expecting is true of C++, but but not C. C does not allow non-`int` enumerators. From N1570 (~C11) §6.7.2.2/2:

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an `int`.

Paragraph 3 also says:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int` and may appear wherever such are permitted.

Para 4 says:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined

`sizeof X == sizeof(int)` is a consequence of para 3, presumably `sizeof M == 4` as well for the same reason. The implementation apparently chose a 64-bit integer type for the enumeration type so `sizeof(enum e_x) == 8` and `sizeof((enum e_x)X)) == 8` as well.

Comment: Surprisingly, `sizeof M == 8`. At the same time `gcc -pedantic` warns that `ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your real issue deals with passing a long long argument to a function with variable arguments:

"How can you deal with it when passing enumeration to a function that uses va_arg?"

You probably can't. In C, functions with variable arguments are limited in the kinds of types they can deal with. Integer types undergo default argument promotion, which changes most or all integral types to int. Here's the best reference I could locate: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html

If you absolutely need to pass a long long, you could probably pass a pointer to it.

Comment: Actually, I'm just learning all the details about `enum`, because I'm trying to find a good application for it.
Since all enumerations are just `int`s I don't find much justification for using enumerated **types** as struct members or function arguments. Even if I declare member of argument as type `enum X`, I can still feed it with any integer number. So enums serve no purpose here other than convenient and automatic incrementation of constant values, and possibly a hint for programmer on what range of `int`s is expected.

Comment: That's a fair assessment. In C, it's more common to use preprocessor macros as constants.

Answer (score 0):

ISO C restricts the enumerator values to the range of `int` only .If you need enumeration constants that don't fit into an `int` you will need to use compiler-specific extensions to do so.

More importantly the compiler is free to choose a smaller type if it can represent the values you define.

Try to compile with `-pedantic` option, you will get the error.